# CAS for algebraic geometry, which one?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, math-software, maple, computer-algebra-systems

I use Maple to compute Groebner bases and find it very efficient/fast for my current needs. However, several introductory textbooks on algebraic geometry refer to Singular, which I never used before. I could not find a comparison of the two computer algebra systems.

1. What are the main differences between Maple and Singular?
2. For large polynomial systems, how does their performance differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singular implements some specialized algorithms that Maple does not, such as the  Shimoyama-Yokoyama algorithm for primary decomposition.  And some of its implementations are better, e.g. the Groebner walk algorithm.  Maple has its strengths as well, such as polynomial factoring and gcd.

Answer (score 5):

Differences: Singular is free; Maple is not. Singular is open source; Maple is only partially open source (the parts written in Maple itself are viewable). Singular is for polynomial computations; Maple is much broader then that. Singular does not have a GUI; Maple has several.